# getting 'FirebaseError: Firebase: Need to provide options, when not being deployed to hosting via source. (app/no-options).' when initializin firebase

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, next.js, firebase-authentication

here is my code:

```
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_KEY,
  authDomain: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_AUTHDOMAIN,
  projectId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_PROJECTID,
  storageBucket: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_STORAGEBUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_MESSAGINGSENDERID,
  appId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_APPID,
  measurementId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_MEASUREMENTID,
}

let app
if (typeof window !== 'undefined' && !getApps().length) {
  app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
} else {
  app = getApp()
}

export const clientAuth = getAuth(app)
```

when i run npm run dev, i get this error
[image]

I tried to comment out the app = getApp()

```
// app = getApp()
```

And got another error:
[image]

what's wrong here?

Comment: Have you tried just `const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig)` without the `if-else` logic?

Comment: @Dharmaraj I got this error instead "Firebase App named '[DEFAULT]' already exists (app/duplicate-app) [duplicate]"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue with the following code

```
const initializeAppIfNecessary = () => {
  try {
    return getApp()
  } catch {
    return initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
  }
}
let app = initializeAppIfNecessary()
const clientAuth = getAuth(app)
```

And the error is now gone